# How to get the statmeant to repeat

Tags: python, function

I am building a battleship game and I would like the user to be able to define how many guesses he should get.I am trying to find a way to repeat this statement (I have it bolded)...maybe a function? If so could you please show me how? Also any suggestions would also be appreciated.

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"

print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

print ship_row
print ship_col

# Guessing Process
hard = 2
medium = 4
easy = 6

***user_guesses = raw_input("What diffuculty do you want to play at; hard, medium or easy?")***

if user_guesses == "hard" :
    user_guesses = hard
elif user_guesses == "medium" :
    user_guesses = medium
elif user_guesses == "easy" :
    user_guesses = easy
else:
    print "Select a diffuculty"
    user_guesses = raw_input("What diffuculty do you want to play at; hard, medium or easy?")



for turn in range(user_guesses):
    print "Turn", turn + 1
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        break
    else:

        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."

        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."

        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"

        print_board(board)

    if turn == 3:
        print "Game Over"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that has a general form of:

- Ask the user for input
- Check that input is a valid choice (from a list of options)
- - Yes? Return the input
- - No?  Repeat

You should write a function for this! Something along the lines of:

```
def input_selection(prompt, choices):
    while True:
        choice = raw_input(prompt)
        if choice in choices:
            return choice
        else:
            print("That's not a valid option!", choices)
```

Then you can just use it:

```
user_guesses = input_selection("What diffuculty do you want to play at?", 
                               ('hard', 'medium', 'easy'))

if user_guesses == "hard":
   user_guesses = hard
elif user_guesses == "medium":
   user_guesses = medium
else:
   user_guesses = easy
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do something to ensure the input is one of the options, then check which it is.

```
user_guesses = raw_input("What diffuculty do you want to play at; hard, medium or easy?")

While user_guesses not in [easy,medium,hard]:
    print "Input not accepted"
    user_guesses = raw_input("What diffuculty do you want to play at; hard, medium or easy?")

if user_guesses == "hard" :
    user_guesses = hard
elif user_guesses == "medium" :
    user_guesses = medium
else:
    user_guesses = easy
```

Comment: this is not even valid `python`.

Comment: i changed the else's to be better, is there something im missing?